# domain/email provider that supports nodemailer?

Tags: node.js, email, nodemailer

I'm building a app that is using nodemailer to send email through gmail (at the moment). However, my customer would like their app to send email from a personalised/custom mail address. I also need a domain name in the same purchase, usually mail addresses are included when purchasing a domain. But I cannot find a provider that clearly states if/not their mailing service supports automated email sending from third-parts like nodemailer. What shall I look for ? Is it a specific kind of auth, or are there a keyword for "automated mail sending support" that I can include in my searches?

Or can anyone point my to a provider that offers this service. I would really like to not purchase a domaine to find out that I can't send mails with nodemailer afterwards.

**My current configuration for node mailer:**

```
const loginEmail = require('../config').nodemailerloginEmail;
const pass = require('../config').nodemailerPassword;

let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
        user: loginEmail,
        pass: pass
    },
    tls: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    }
});
```

Any ideas of how it should look when I use a custom mail service/address?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mailgun](https://www.mailgun.com/) with nodemailer. They have a free sandbox option that will allow you to test with nodemailer and then you can upgrade if you want to send from your own custom domain.

```
const transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: "Mailgun",
  auth: {
    user: settings.MAILGUN_USER,
    pass: settings.MAILGUN_PASS
  },
  tls: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm gonna look into this. That could be a possible solution, but a pity that it requires two payments/subscriptions, both the domain and mailgun. Preferable would be a domain provider that support nodemailer directly. still can't find anything about that on google.